# Exporting Template Instantiations Automatically Inside Another Class

Tags: c++, templates, dll, stl

I am writing a helper class for a DLL project that I am working on which uses the PImpl idiom. To avoid repetitive code, I have created a template PImpl class which should make it easy to adopt this idiom in exported library classes so I don't have to expose class internals.

Here is the important part of the PImpl template class:

```
//Class for easy adoption of the PImpl idiom
template<typename PImpl_T>
class __declspec(dllexport) PImpl
{
public:
    extern template class __declspec(dllexport) std::unique_ptr<PImpl_T>;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<PImpl_T> m_pImpl;
};
```

However, C++ doesn't like me automatically exporting the std::unique_ptr definition inside the class. I am trying to avoid having to export every unique pointer template instantiation separately, so I am wondering if there is a way of doing it automatically.

Here is an example of how I would use this helper class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass :
    private PImpl<struct MyClassImpl>
{ /* class definition in here */ };
```

The MyClassImpl structure would then only be defined in the CPP file, which the user of the library would never see.

How can I avoid having to export each unique pointer template instantiation separately?

Note that I am aware this code will not work for different versions of the C++ STL; it can be assumed that users will be using exactly the same version of STL and even using the same compiler.

C++ version: 11 or newer.
Compiler: Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't export a template from a DLL - there's no actual machine code behind a template, there's nothing to export. You can only export instantiations of a template, with specific template arguments. Another way to think of it: a template describes an infinite family of classes or functions, but a DLL cannot have an infinite number of exported symbols.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `PImpl` is supposed to be used. Its `m_pImpl` member is private, `MyClass` doesn't have access to it. What exactly does the implementation of `MyClass` look like, and how does it make use of `MyClassImpl`?

Comment: I omitted the rest of the class - I have a GetImpl() function which is protected and returns a reference to the Impl structure, but I didn't consider it part of the question so I didn't include it. Can you suggest an alternative, or must I export each instantiation of std::unique_ptr?

Comment: I don't think you actually need to export `PImpl`, or `std::unique_ptr<MyClassImpl>`. I know MSVC issues a warning, but this warning is misguided and can be safely ignored (or disabled).

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Why is there a warning in the first place then?

Comment: Well, if you use class `A` as part of the public interface of class `B`, and you export `B` from a DLL, you should also export `A`. But if `A` is only used privately, as an internal implementation detail, then it doesn't need to be exported. Perhaps the compiler has difficulty distinguishing these two cases, and errs on the side of caution.

Comment: Okay, well thank you very much! I'll ignore this warning then.